# How to give background images in select tag in pure css?

Tags: forms, css

I want to do this

[image]

This is select drop down of form

My code is

**HMTL**

```
<select>
                        <option>Country</option>
                        <option>India</option>
                        <option>USA</option>
                    </select>
```

**Css**

```
select{
    width:197px;
    height:45px;
    border:solid 1px #13669b;
    box-shadow:0 5px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.06) inset;
    background:rgba(256,256,256,0.7);
    color:#13669b;
    font-size:16px;
    font-family: 'LatoBold';
    padding:0 14px;
    line-height:45px;
}
```

I want to this only **pure css**. How?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to create a dropdown box like that with pure css (yet).

You can create your own js/css dropdown plugin or use one of the many jQuery/css plugins already available.

Comment: hey @akalucas  i want to used css3 and i want to used pure css in my projects . I know there is many option in javascript.........

Comment: You _can't_ do it with pure CSS, so you're going to have to buckle and use a Javascript solution. There's one [here](http://jamwaffles.co.uk/jquery/listex) that uses jQuery.

Comment: @RohitAzad you could use css3 to make a <div> or other element look like a dropdown box. However you will always end up using a minimal amount of javascript for handling the click events.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there is EASY *cross browser* way to do it but if you with combination of CSS + jQuery, you can get it working in all browsers in use:

- [Reinventing a Drop Down with CSS and jQuery](http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx)

See the tutorial on how to do it and modify the CSS for the look you want.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: @RohitAzad: I hope you find a solution with pure CSS which is ***cross browser***

Answer (score 0):

This solution works with pure CSS but it's Chrome-related. See the following example:

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-padding-end: 20px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 2px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  background-image: url(../images/select-arrow.png), 
    -webkit-linear-gradient(#FAFAFA, #F4F4F4 40%, #E5E5E5);
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
  color: #555;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Haven't tried to replace the `-webkit` prefix by a `-moz` one for it to be compatible with Firefox browsers, it might actually work as well, you should give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

Dropdowns are implemented differently in different browsers, and styling is not widely supported. This has it's reasons. For one: consider the dropdowns on iPads/iPhones. They work radically different than desktop application dropdowns.

If you want a styled dropdown, you will have to build it yourself with lists and javascript. Or use one of numerous libraries available for this (which is further proof that no pure CSS solution is available).